# Generating two-element tuples of coordinates in a function

Tags: python, pygame

I need a function to pass coordinates as tuples, e.g. (x, y).

This is for my first project.

I want to create a Chessboard with pygame by simply blit white and black squares on the display.

Now, I have managed to blit all the white squares at the right destinations.

What I am trying to do here, is to automate the creation of white squares (later the same will happen with black ones), and more precisely, I am trying to pass the following tuples:

```
    # first column
    window.blit(square, (0, 0))
    window.blit(square, (0, 200))
    window.blit(square, (0, 400))
    window.blit(square, (0, 600))
    window.blit(square, (0, 800))
    # second column
    window.blit(square, (100, 100))
    window.blit(square, (100, 300))
    window.blit(square, (100, 500))
    window.blit(square, (100, 700))
    # third column
    window.blit(square, (200, 0))
    window.blit(square, (200, 200))
    window.blit(square, (200, 400))
    window.blit(square, (200, 600))
    window.blit(square, (200, 800))
    # fourth column
    window.blit(square, (300, 100))
    window.blit(square, (300, 300))
    window.blit(square, (300, 500))
    window.blit(square, (300, 700))
    # fifth column
    window.blit(square, (400, 0))
    window.blit(square, (400, 200))
    window.blit(square, (400, 400))
    window.blit(square, (400, 600))
    window.blit(square, (400, 800))
    # seventh column
    window.blit(square, (500, 100))
    window.blit(square, (500, 300))
    window.blit(square, (500, 500))
    window.blit(square, (500, 700))
    # seventh column
    window.blit(square, (600, 0))
    window.blit(square, (600, 200))
    window.blit(square, (600, 400))
    window.blit(square, (600, 600))
    window.blit(square, (600, 800))
    # eighth column
    window.blit(square, (700, 100))
    window.blit(square, (700, 300))
    window.blit(square, (700, 500))
    window.blit(square, (700, 700))
```

In my coordinator function, I have managed to write the following code, but from here on I don't really know what to do:

```
def coordinator():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for column in range(0, 5):
        print((x, y))
        y += 200

    x = 200
    y = 0
    for column in range(0, 5):
        print((x, y))
        y += 200


coordinator()
```

Which gives as output:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 200)
(0, 400)
(0, 600)
(0, 800)
(200, 0)
(200, 200)
(200, 400)
(200, 600)
(200, 800)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Ok guys good news, I have managed to write some code which prints all the coordinates I need. here is my 'Main' class, and namely display.py:

```
import pygame
import sys
from coordinator import coordinator

pygame.init()
window_size = (800, 800)
game_window = pygame.display.set_mode(size=window_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')


while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()


    class WhiteSquare:
        height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        a = height
        b = width
        white_square = pygame.Surface((a, b))
        white_square.fill((255, 255, 255), )

    ws = WhiteSquare()


    class BlueSquare:
        height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        a = height
        b = width
        blue_square = pygame.Surface((a, b))
        blue_square.fill((0, 0, 255), )

    bs = BlueSquare()


    class ChessBoard:
        game_window.blit(ws.white_square, (0, 0))
        game_window.blit(bs.blue_square, (0, 100))





    cb = ChessBoard()

    coordinator()

    pygame.display.update()
```

For those solutions proposed which have got a black_square or refer to a black square in any manner, I have obviously changed my 'blue' into 'black'. I am only using a blue colour because I want to make sure that also black squares are working right on a black background (if that makes sense).

Here is the coordinator.py which works good enough by its own. The problem arises when I try to call it in the display.py file.

Have a look:

```
def coordinator():
    o = white_odd_columns()
    e = white_even_columns()
    print('o: ' + str(o))
    print('e: ' + str(e))


def white_odd_columns():
    for x in range(0, 800, 200):
        print('odd column: ')
        y = 0
        for first_column in range(0, 5):
            odd_coordinate = (x, y)
            print('This is odd_coordinate ' + str(odd_coordinate))
            y += 200
            #return odd_coordinate

def white_even_columns():
    for x in range(100, 800, 200):
        print('even column: ')
        y = 100
        for first_column in range(0, 4):
            even_coordinate = (x, y)
            print('This is even_coordinate ' + str(even_coordinate))
            y += 200
            #return even_coordinate

white_even_columns()
white_odd_columns()
coordinator()
```

Now, when I run coordinator I get the following output:

```
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (100, 100)
This is even_coordinate (100, 300)
This is even_coordinate (100, 500)
This is even_coordinate (100, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (300, 100)
This is even_coordinate (300, 300)
This is even_coordinate (300, 500)
This is even_coordinate (300, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (500, 100)
This is even_coordinate (500, 300)
This is even_coordinate (500, 500)
This is even_coordinate (500, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (700, 100)
This is even_coordinate (700, 300)
This is even_coordinate (700, 500)
This is even_coordinate (700, 700)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (0, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (200, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (400, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (600, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (0, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (0, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (200, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (200, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (400, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (400, 800)
odd column: 
This is odd_coordinate (600, 0)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 200)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 400)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 600)
This is odd_coordinate (600, 800)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (100, 100)
This is even_coordinate (100, 300)
This is even_coordinate (100, 500)
This is even_coordinate (100, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (300, 100)
This is even_coordinate (300, 300)
This is even_coordinate (300, 500)
This is even_coordinate (300, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (500, 100)
This is even_coordinate (500, 300)
This is even_coordinate (500, 500)
This is even_coordinate (500, 700)
even column: 
This is even_coordinate (700, 100)
This is even_coordinate (700, 300)
This is even_coordinate (700, 500)
This is even_coordinate (700, 700)
o: None
e: None
```

The problem I have got is that in coordinator.py, when I run the coordinator() function, I would like to see a list of tuples with all the coordinates, so that I can then easily access them through the list index.

If that works, then hopefully I can pass the coordinates to the ChessBoard class.

I will keep trying your solutions, although they are a bit too difficult to understand for me since I have just started with python and pygame.

This said, thanks for your time guys, I will keep an eye on your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the modulo operator to generate "every-other" style coordinates.

```py
for row in range(8):
    for col in range(8):
        if col % 2 == row % 2:
            x = col * 100
            y = row * 100
            window.blit(square, (x, y))
```

has the same effect as your original code.

To draw both black and white squares in a single pass,

```py
for row in range(8):
    for col in range(8):
        is_black = (col % 2 == row % 2)
        x = col * 100
        y = row * 100
        window.blit((black_square if is_black else white_square), (x, y))
```

(assuming you have `black_square` and `white_square` sprites)

Comment: Hi AKX, thanks for your answer. I have tried your second solution, but I get 'Type error: argument 1 must be pygame. Surface, not type'. Thing is that black_square and white_square are both pygame.surface. I could post my display.py code (the main class), but not sure how to do it. should I just edit my initial question?

Comment: I think you have a `black_square = pygame.Surface` somewhere, instead of `pygame.Surface(...)` or an equivalent load code.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of this answer, I'm giving you the function that will produce *all* coordinates for the chessboard, together with the right square to blit:

```
for square, coord in coordinator((ws.white_square, bs.blue_square)):
    window.blit(square, coord)
```

but I'll first cover how you can solve this problem with a few different loop approaches.

The simplest thing to do is to create a list, and appending your coordinates:

```
def coordinator():
    coordinates = []
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for column in range(0, 5):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
        y += 200

    x = 200
    y = 0
    for column in range(0, 5):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
        y += 200
    return coordinates
```

and the caller can then loop over the list for each tuple:

```
for coord in coordinator():
    window.blit(square, coord)
```

Note that you can simplify your loops greatly; `y` can be calculated by multiplying, and you could just append both the `(0, ...)` and `(200, ...)` tuples in the same iteration:

```
def coordinator():
    coordinates = []
    for column in range(5):
        coordinates.append((0, column * 200))
        coordinates.append((200, column * 200))
    return coordinates
```

or, instead of a column counter, you could tell `range()` to make steps of 200:

```
def coordinator():
    coordinates = []
    for y in range(0, 900, 200):
        coordinates.append((0, y))
        coordinates.append((200, y))
    return coordinates
```

You could also make `x` a loop, over the two values that it takes:

```
def coordinator():
    coordinates = []
    for x in (0, 200):
        for y in range(0, 900, 200):
            coordinates.append((x, y))
    return coordinates
```

This then can be turned into a single list comprehension:

```
def coordinator():
    return [(x, y) for x in (0, 200) for y in range(0, 900, 200)]
```

You don't really need the whole list, you could also make this a generator expression; this produces values *on demand*, and once each coordinate has been used, the memory is cleared again:

```
def coordinator():
    return ((x, y) for x in (0, 200) for y in range(0, 900, 200))
```

I only replaced `[... for target in iterable]` with `(... for target in iterable)` to tell Python to not keep everything in memory.

Of course, this all only produces the output you already created with `print()` statements.

To produce *all possible white squares* (100x100 squares across 9 rows, with 5 odd squares in even rows, 4 even squares in odd rows), you can just use a full `range()` for `x` and add another such loop for the odd columns:

```
for x in range(0, 900, 200):
    for y in range(0, 900, 200):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
for x in range(100, 900, 200):
    for y in range(100, 900, 200):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
```

Note that the only thing that changed for the second set of loops is the start value for `y`. You could, in fact, work out what that start value is from `x`, if `x`, divided the square size (100) is even, you want `y` to start at `0`, otherwise you want `y` to start at `100`. Make `x` step in increments of 100:

```
for x in range(0, 900, 100):
    even = (x // 100) % 2 == 0  # true for even, false for odd
    for y in range(0 if even else 100, 900, 200):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
```

This produces all your expected coordinates, from `(0, 0), (0, 200), (0, 400), (0, 600), (0, 800)` for the first row and `(100, 100), (100, 300), (100, 500), (100, 700)` for the second row all the way up to `(800, 0), (800, 200), (800, 400), (800, 600), (800, 800)` for the last row.

Note that it is better to not hard-code the numbers in the above, it would be better for the width, height and square size to be configurable. As a function, that then becomes:

```
def coordinator(boardsize=900, squaresize=100):
    coordinates = []
    for x in range(0, boardsize, squaresize):
        even = x // squaresize % 2 == 0  # true for even, false for odd
        for y in range(0 if even else squaresize, boardsize, squaresize * 2):
            coordinates.append((x, y))
    return coordinates
```

which produces your exact output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(coordinator())
[(0, 0),
 (0, 200),
 (0, 400),
 (0, 600),
 (0, 800),
 (100, 100),
 (100, 300),
 (100, 500),
 (100, 700),
 (200, 0),
 (200, 200),
 (200, 400),
 (200, 600),
 (200, 800),
 (300, 100),
 (300, 300),
 (300, 500),
 (300, 700),
 (400, 0),
 (400, 200),
 (400, 400),
 (400, 600),
 (400, 800),
 (500, 100),
 (500, 300),
 (500, 500),
 (500, 700),
 (600, 0),
 (600, 200),
 (600, 400),
 (600, 600),
 (600, 800),
 (700, 100),
 (700, 300),
 (700, 500),
 (700, 700),
 (800, 0),
 (800, 200),
 (800, 400),
 (800, 600),
 (800, 800)]
```

This is not enough however, as this is just the *white* squares. You'd have to flip the logic to produce the blue squares.

However, it would actually be *easier to just produce **all** squares*, and let the function tell you what square to put there. You'd generate all coordinates, incrementing `x` and `y` by 100 (`(0, 0), (0, 100), (0, 200), ..., (100, 0), (100, 100), (100, 200), ...`, etc.) and then combine those with alternating white and blue squares.

The easiest way to do this, is to use the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html); it has a function to generate the Cartesian product needed for the `(x, y)` coordinates ([`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)) and it has a function to repeatedly alternate between the squares ([`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)):

```
from itertools import cycle, product

def coordinator(squares, boardsize=900, squaresize=100):
    # (x, y), from (0, 0) through to (800, 800)
    coordinates = product(range(0, boardsize, squaresize), repeat=2)
    # endless series of white, blue, white, blue, white, blue, ...
    squares_cycle = cycle(squares)
    return zip(squares_cycle, coordinates)
```

This produces `(square, (x, y))` values for you; I used the strings `'white'` and `'blue'` only to demonstrate the result:

```
>>> pprint(list(coordinator(("white", "blue"))))
[('white', (0, 0)),
 ('blue', (0, 100)),
 ('white', (0, 200)),
 ('blue', (0, 300)),
 ('white', (0, 400)),
 ('blue', (0, 500)),
 ('white', (0, 600)),
 ('blue', (0, 700)),
 ('white', (0, 800)),
 ('blue', (100, 0)),
 ('white', (100, 100)),
 ('blue', (100, 200)),
 ('white', (100, 300)),
 ('blue', (100, 400)),
 ('white', (100, 500)),
 ('blue', (100, 600)),
 ('white', (100, 700)),
 ('blue', (100, 800)),
 ('white', (200, 0)),
 ('blue', (200, 100)),
 ('white', (200, 200)),
 ('blue', (200, 300)),
 ('white', (200, 400)),
 ('blue', (200, 500)),
 ('white', (200, 600)),
 ('blue', (200, 700)),
 ('white', (200, 800)),
 ('blue', (300, 0)),
 ('white', (300, 100)),
 ('blue', (300, 200)),
 ('white', (300, 300)),
 ('blue', (300, 400)),
 ('white', (300, 500)),
 ('blue', (300, 600)),
 ('white', (300, 700)),
 ('blue', (300, 800)),
 ('white', (400, 0)),
 ('blue', (400, 100)),
 ('white', (400, 200)),
 ('blue', (400, 300)),
 ('white', (400, 400)),
 ('blue', (400, 500)),
 ('white', (400, 600)),
 ('blue', (400, 700)),
 ('white', (400, 800)),
 ('blue', (500, 0)),
 ('white', (500, 100)),
 ('blue', (500, 200)),
 ('white', (500, 300)),
 ('blue', (500, 400)),
 ('white', (500, 500)),
 ('blue', (500, 600)),
 ('white', (500, 700)),
 ('blue', (500, 800)),
 ('white', (600, 0)),
 ('blue', (600, 100)),
 ('white', (600, 200)),
 ('blue', (600, 300)),
 ('white', (600, 400)),
 ('blue', (600, 500)),
 ('white', (600, 600)),
 ('blue', (600, 700)),
 ('white', (600, 800)),
 ('blue', (700, 0)),
 ('white', (700, 100)),
 ('blue', (700, 200)),
 ('white', (700, 300)),
 ('blue', (700, 400)),
 ('white', (700, 500)),
 ('blue', (700, 600)),
 ('white', (700, 700)),
 ('blue', (700, 800)),
 ('white', (800, 0)),
 ('blue', (800, 100)),
 ('white', (800, 200)),
 ('blue', (800, 300)),
 ('white', (800, 400)),
 ('blue', (800, 500)),
 ('white', (800, 600)),
 ('blue', (800, 700)),
 ('white', (800, 800))]
```

All *your* code has to do is give this function your `ws.white_square` and `bs.blue_square` square values, then use the output of each iteration step to blit with:

```
for square, coord in coordinator((ws.white_square, bs.blue_square)):
    window.blit(square, coord)
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can now vary the *size of the board* as well as vary the size of the squares. Your board has 9 x 9 squares and so must produce alternating rows:

```
１  ２  ３  ４  ５  ６  ７  ８  ９
┌───────────────────────────┐
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ １
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ２
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ３
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ４
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ５
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ６
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ７
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ８
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ９
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
└───────────────────────────┘
```

but [actual chess boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard) have *eight* rows and columns:

```
１  ２  ３  ４  ５  ６  ７  ８
┌────────────────────────┐
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ １
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ２
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ３
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ４
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ５
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ６
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│ ７
│░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓│
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│ ８
│▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░▓▓▓░░░│
└────────────────────────┘
```

Note that in this case there are the *same number of white and blue squares on each row*.

To generate that kind of board, all you have to do is adjust your board size, and optionally adjust the square size. A 800x800 pixel board would produce the correct output instantly:

```
for square, coords in coordinator((ws.white_square, bs.blue_square), 800):
    # ...
```

because the `range()` value is easily adjusted an the squares keep on alternating, regardless.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you for your time. your first two blocks of code are close to what I was looking for, but when I print coord it only returns the first and third column coordinates, not all of the column.

Comment: @MirkoOricci: right, because I replicated your first piece of output only. I'll update.

Comment: @MirkoOricci: right, you now have complete chessboard coordinate solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I think I have done it! I get the exact output I wanted** (got a brand new problem now, but will post a new question).

Here is the coordinator:

```
# Returns two list of tuples, one for even columns (white squares), and
# one for odd columns (white squares).

# Needs to be implemented to achieve the same for black squares.

def coordinator():
    odd_columns = white_odd_columns()
    even_columns = white_even_columns()
    columns = [odd_columns, even_columns]
    # print(columns)
    return columns
    # print('odd_columns: ' + str(odd_columns))
    # print('even_columns: ' + str(even_columns))

# Returns a list with coordinates
# for white squares in odd columns
def white_odd_columns():
    odd_coordinates = []
    for x in range(0, 800, 200):
        y = 0
        for first_column in range(0, 5):
            odd_coordinates.append((x, y))
            y += 200
    # print('This should be the complete list of odd coordinates' + str(odd_coordinates))
    return odd_coordinates

# Returns a list with coordinates
# for white squares in even columns
def white_even_columns():
    even_coordinates = []
    for x in range(100, 800, 200):
        y = 100
        for first_column in range(0, 4):
            even_coordinates.append((x, y))
            y += 200
    # print('This should be the complete list of even coordinates' + str(even_coordinates))
    return even_coordinates

# white_even_columns()
# white_odd_columns()
coordinator()
```

And here is the output (a list of two lists of tuples - odd columns, and even columns, basically all the coordinates):

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 200), (0, 400), (0, 600), (0, 800), (200, 0), (200, 200), (200, 400), (200, 600), (200, 800), (400, 0), (400, 200), (400, 400), (400, 600), (400, 800), (600, 0), (600, 200), (600, 400), (600, 600), (600, 800)], [(100, 100), (100, 300), (100, 500), (100, 700), (300, 100), (300, 300), (300, 500), (300, 700), (500, 100), (500, 300), (500, 500), (500, 700), (700, 100), (700, 300), (700, 500), (700, 700)]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I consider my question answered, but I will keep your ones in mind when I will update the final solutions. Thank you, guys.